# Fadeo Galerkin method to prouve existence of parabolic problem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

we have the following problem
$$
\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} - \Delta u + F(u)= f(x,t); t >0, x \in \mathbb{R}^n; \ u(x,0)=0
$$
where $F$ is n linear, lipchitzian increazing function.

My question is how we prouve the existence of solution of this problem using Fadeo Galerkin method?
I learn books but i don't found application of Fadeo Galerkin in the general case when F is no linear.

Thank's in advance to the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it in PDEs book of L. C. Evans.

Comment: partial differential equations lawrence c. evans

Comment: I have this book but i don't see my problem with general non linear function F. In wich page we can fund it? Plesase. I have the book who's in the following link: https://libgen.pw/item/adv/5a1f046d3a044650f5faacc5

Comment: Can you help me please

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can not apply the Faedo-Galerkin method, it is not applicable in a free domain $\mathbb{R}^n$, the spectrum of the Laplacian is not discrete, in your case, there is no eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the Laplacian you can not make the approximation.